# Горячие клавиши pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть ли в pycharm функция множественного выделения как в sublime text(можно поставить много курсоров и одновременно в разных строках редактировать текст, в sublime <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + клик мышкой). А также очень не хватает возможности быстро выделить одинаковое слово, в sublime - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. А также как вы решаете проблему одинаковых сочетаний горячих клавиш в линкусе и в самом пайчарме, например <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> в pycharm должен запустить reformat code но в линуксе это блокирует экран.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, у меня просто была версия pycharm 3.1, а фича мультивыделения появилась в 3.4, после обновления все прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1):

> можно поставить много курсоров и одновременно в разных строках редактировать текст, в sublime ctrl + клик мышкой

Alt, если правильно помню

> очень не хватает возможности быстро выделить одинаковое слово, в sublime - ctrl + D.

ctrl + w

Comment: ctrl+w просто выделяет слово, строку, блок, в зависимости сколько раз нажмешь, в sublime text если нажать ctrl + D (при выделенном слове или символе) выделялось следующее слово в файле которое соответствует выделенному.

Comment: alt + j выделяет все похожие слова

Answer (score 0):

У меня стоят настройки от *Visual Studio*, но `Keymap->Editor Actions->Column Selection Mode` стоит `Alt+Shift+Insert`.

Нажимаешь, потом выделяешь несколько строк `Shift+Up/Down`.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли в pycharm функция множественного выделения как в sublime text(можно поставить много курсоров и одновременно в разных строках редактировать текст, в sublime Ctrl + клик мышкой)

`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + клик  - работает

Answer (score 0):

- Mac OS Cataline 10.15.4
- PyCharm 2020.1 (Community Edition) Build #PC-201.6668.115, built on April 7, 2020

комбо клавиш: `Alt` + click

Answer (score -1):

Можно так попробовать: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>